# Is it possible to play a sound though the audio driver with Rtmidi?

Tags: c++, audio, midi

I am currently on linux and I am playing around with [rtmidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/). Now I was able to play a sound though my digital piano but I am wondering if I can also output the sound though my speakers?

When my digital piano is not connected I still get one device with `getPortCount();` I assumed that is my audio driver. The device name is `Midi Through:0` which is somewhat strange.

But I don't hear any sound and I am not sure if that is the intended behavior. Can I play midi sounds though my audio driver with rtmidi? Or do I need another library for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert MIDI commands into real sounds, you need a synthesizer.

Sound cards stopped having a built-in hardware synthesizer in the last millenium.
You need a software synthesizer, such as Fluidsynth or Timidity.

Comment: So in summary, he will still need external software.

Answer (score 1):

RtMidi is, as quoted from this [website](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/), a realtime *midi* input/output API. It does not say it is an *audio* API or library therefore it probably isn't. So yes, you will need another library or API for this, I recommend OpenAL.